# how to set the legend for certain axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(team_3_F = c("browingal ", "newyorkish", "site", 
"team ", "browingal ", "newyorkish", "site", "team ", "browingal ", 
"newyorkish", "site", "team ", "browingal ", "newyorkish", "site", 
"team "), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("No.T", "AAA_BBB_US", 
"AAA_CCC_US", "AAA_BBB_CCC_US"), class = "factor"), value = c(12, 
4, 6, 22, 0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0, 0.181818181818182, 0.0833333333333333, 
1, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0833333333333333, 0.25, 0, 0.0909090909090909
)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot it like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = variable)) +
  stat_summary_2d(
    aes(z = value, fill = after_stat(value)),
    geom = "tile")+
  geom_text(aes(label=round(value,2)))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Percent"))
```

How can I guide the legend to only show the trend color for `AAA_BBB_US` , `AAA_BBB_CCC_US` , `AAA_CCC_US` but not for No.T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the mapping of `z` inside `stat_summary_2d` using `ifelse`, to set the value of `z` to `NA` when `variable == 'No.T'`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = variable)) +
  stat_summary_2d(
    aes(z = ifelse(variable == 'No.T', NA, value), fill = after_stat(value)),
    geom = "tile") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Percent")) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]